# How to View Data In SSRS Reports

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package, There are only two tasks in my SSIS package. One is Execute SQL Task and another one is Data Flow Task. My first task is doing to truncate a table (Table_1) and second task is just load data in truncated table means Table_1. An SSRS report get data from that table means Table_1. My SSIS packages run every hour. when SSIS package running in the same time users has complaining that they are not able to view data in the report. How do I do that my SSIS package start running. Users can able to view data in my Report.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, have a table that stores values on whether this deal is running or not, doing something like setting a single value to 1 when running and 0 when not running.

Then in your SSRS, instead of a 'SELECT * FROM Table_1', write a stored procedure that has logic  to lookup the value in the above table.  If 0 return the set normally, if 1 then return some kind of friendly message that data is currently being loaded and the report is not available.